# Set State inside axios post method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have axios post method to check `username` and password when they available I want to set a state as `true` but always get the state as `false`.

My code is:

```js
const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);

const login = () => {

    Axios.post('http://124.43.17.60:4000/loginnew', {
        username: email,
        password: password

    }).then((response) => {
        // let data = response.data
        console.log("my web response all", response)
        console.log("my web response", response.data[0])
        try {
            if (response.data[0].role) {
                let role = response.data[0].role
                setValidated(true)
                console.log(validated)
                if (role == "admin") {
                    history.push('/admin')
                } else {
                    history.push('/member')
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            alert.error("wrong credentials");
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone tell me what um doing wrong and please help me to solve this problem

Comment: From where you are calling login function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, modifying the state is an asynchronous action. Meaning that this piece of code won't give your expected results:

```
setValidated(true)
console.log(validated) // Won't be updated to true
```

If you want to achieve something specifically on `true`, you have 2 options

#### 1. useEffect

```js
useEffect(() => { if (validated) { ...do something... } }, [validated])
```

#### 2. setState callback

```js
setValidated((oldValidated) => {
  const newValidated = !oldValidated;
  console.log(newValidated) // true if oldValidated was false

  // do something with newValidated === true

  return newValidated; // Make sure to return the new value, otherwise state won't update at all.
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , using second method I have archived my target

Answer (score 1):

You cannot view the "updated" state inside you `login` function as `setValidated` is an asynchronous process, which mean the code will not wait for the data to get back and still use the old value. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) for more explanation
If you want to view the "updated" value of `validated` you need to create a `useEffect` like so

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(validated)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post('http://124.43.17.60:4000/loginnew', {
        username: email,
        password: password

    }).then((response) => {
        // let data = response.data
        console.log("my web response all", response)
        console.log("my web response", response.data[0])
        try {
            if (response.data[0].role) {
                let role = response.data[0].role
                setValidated(true)
                console.log(validated)
                if (role == "admin") {
                    history.push('/admin')
                } else {
                    history.push('/member')
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            alert.error("wrong credentials");
        }
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: but this login function called only when clicked not in useEffect